# Simple program to tell if number is even or odd, negatives all show as even

Tags: c++, math

So I'm prepping for my programming class in the spring and the notes for the class are asking for a self assessment.  I wrote this program that it asked in about 3 minutes flat but I'm unsure why it's showing all negative numbers as even.  Any ideas?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x,y;

    cout << "Enter a number for reference" << endl;
    cin >> x;

    cout << endl << "The Number you entered was: " << x << endl;

    y = x%2;

    if (x<0 && x!=0) {
        cout << endl <<"The Number you entered is negative" << endl;
    }
    else if(x==0) {
        cout << endl << "The number is neither negative or positive" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << endl << "The Number you entered is Positive" << endl;
    }

    if (y>0 /*&& x!=0*/) {
        cout << "The Number you entered is odd" << endl;
    }
    else if(x==0) {
        cout << "The number you entered is neither even or odd" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "The Number you entered is even" << endl;
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#Common_pitfalls

Comment: What did you find `y` to be when `x` is negative?

Comment: If `(x < 0)` evalautes to true, then `(x < 0 && x != 0)` is bound to be true.  Your problem is that `-1 % 2` is `-1`, so you have `y < 0` but you report that as even.

Comment: In C, the result of modulo with negative arguments is defined to be machine dependent.  Early C++ kept the same rule.  I think a recent C++ standard made it not machine dependent.

Answer (score 2):

All integers are either even or odd, there should be no case "The number you have entered is neither even nor odd" !

You can do this:

```
if ( y == 0 )
{
    cout << "The Number you entered is even" << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "The Number you entered is odd" << endl;
}
```

This works because the definition of *even* is *equal to 0 mod 2* which is exactly what doing `% 2` then checking `== 0` does.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>

bool isEven(int n) {
    if (n % 2 == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

int main() {

    int myNumber = 0;

    std::cout << "Enter number: ";
    std::cin >> myNumber;

    if (isEven(myNumber))
        std::cout << myNumber << " is even." << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << myNumber << " is odd." << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Firstly, the sign of a number has nothing to do with whether it is odd or even. Secondly, zero is an even number (0 is a whole integer multiple of two; 0 x 2). The above code asks for an input integer, the function isEven(n) then returns true or false as to whether there is a remainder when divided by two.

Answer (score 1):

The possible results of `%` operation (`y` in your program) are:

- positive 1 (if x is a positive odd number)
- zero (if x is a even number or zero)
- negative 1 (if x is a negative odd number)

So if `y` is zero, you need to check `x` to determine 'even' or `neither odd nor even`.
but in your code where you should be checking for the case of `y` being zero, you are only checking the value of `x`.

The effect is that for every negative `x`, (resulting in `y == 0` or `y < 0`), the last `else` statement will execute.